# Android Emulator not support face detection

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection

I got this error when start face detection
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid face detection type=0`

to getMaxNumDetectedFaces is 0

is there any way to fix this with kotlin in android studio

Comment: Please provide more information. You can post the code which is causing problem

Comment: It may be because your virtual device is not set to support face detection. I am not sure if that is possible in the emulator. If it is set to 0, then you should probably not start the detection.

Comment: Recommended approach for face detection from android camera api: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera ```public void startFaceDetection(){
    // Try starting Face Detection
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    // start face detection only *after* preview has started
    if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0){
        // camera supports face detection, so can start it:
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
    }
}```

Comment: What I want to know if there is a way to set the number, to change the default 0?